# Facet for Empty or null values for any field in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, facet, solrnet, solr-search

I am using Facet in my solr implemententation. Facets are display for all the keywords of fields having concrete values.

Facets are not displayed for the empty values. I want to show a facets for empty values as well.

For example, in below example data facet is displayed for the value in Country field as

[Sample Data for Solr fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnyP7.png)

US (6)
CA (5)
IND (5)

I also want to show facet as 
[Empty] (7)

Please suggest some workaround to get Facet for empty values.

Answer (score 4):

You can [use `facet.missing` to get a count for the number of documents that doesn't have a value in the field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.missingParameter).

> The `facet.missing` Parameter
>
> If set to true, this parameter indicates that, in addition to the Term-based constraints of a facet field, a count of all results that match the query but which have no facet value for the field should be computed and returned in the response.
>
> The default value is `false`.
>
> This parameter can be specified on a per-field basis with the syntax of `f.<fieldname>.facet.missing`.